# code 401,The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, in-app-billing, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have done the following:

1. Create a GCP project
2. Enable Google Play Android Developer API in GCP project
3. Create a service account and authorize [Service Account Admin] and [Service Account User]
4. Create a json key for the service account, and download the json file to configure on my backend server
5. In the Google Play console, link the GCP project I created
6. In the Google Play console, enable the Play Android Developer API
7. Grant service account financial permissions
8. Add the service account to the licensing test

(refer to some practices on the Internet)
9. Edit in-app product/subscription information to update
10. After waiting one night (maybe more) and then doing some other attempts, I don't know if I need to wait any longer.

Then I use the backend server to call the interface: `androidpublisher.SubscriptionPurchasesService.Get`

I will get a 401 error: the specific error is as follows:

```
{
    "msg":{
        "error":{
            "code":401,
            "message":"The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
            "errors":[
                {
                    "message":"The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
                    "domain":"androidpublisher",
                    "reason":"permissionDenied"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some operational records:

[1. Create a service account in a GCP project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgPyv.png)

[2. create json secret key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ68i.png)

[3. Associate the Google Play console with the GCP project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7INp.png)

[4. Service account displayed in GooGoogle play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roruC.png)

[5. Grant service account financial permissions in GooGoogle play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izJF0.png)

[6. Add service account to licensing test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjPJH.png)

[7. Access the API using the backend server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S0dp.png)

[8. Error 401,the nightmare begins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44UdI.png)

Comment: Were you able fix this ?